# Goland reading liner per line output of a command

Tags: go

I would like to read an output command line per line. For this I use the `StdoutPipe` method and the `bufio` library:

```
package main

import (
        "encoding/json"
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "os/exec"
        "bufio"
)


func main() {
        cmd := exec.Command("printf", "{\"Name\": \"Bob\", \"Age\": 1}\n%.0s", "{1..5}")
        stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)
        if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
        var person struct {
                Name string
                Age  int
        }
        for scanner.Scan() {
                if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(scanner.Text()), &person); err != nil {
                        log.Fatal(err)
                } else {
                        fmt.Printf("%s is %d years old\n", person.Name, person.Age)
                }
        }
        if err := cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
}
```

I should obtain 5 lines:

```
$ printf "{\"Name\": \"Bob\", \"Age\": 1}\n%.0s" {1..5}
{"Name": "Bob", "Age": 1}
{"Name": "Bob", "Age": 1}
{"Name": "Bob", "Age": 1}
{"Name": "Bob", "Age": 1}
{"Name": "Bob", "Age": 1}
```

The point is that I only get the first line. I am quite new on `Go`and I guess the usage of the StdoutPipe is incorrect.

Comment: You have a single result. How many lines you should obtain? For me the code looks good.

Comment: @SimoEndre: I should obtain 5 lines. I have edited the post with the output from shell command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{1..5}` is expanded to `1 2 3 4 5` by the shell, so you must do it yourself:

```
cmd := exec.Command("printf", `{"Name": "Bob", "Age": %s}\n`, `1`, `2`) // etc.
```

Also note the use of raw strings, its much more convenient than constantly escaping everything. And on a related note, instead of `[]byte(scanner.Text())` you should really use `scanner.Bytes()`.