# Is there a concept of reading the output of a program line by line, as a stream?

Tags: go, stream, command, output, line

I have a shell command (e.g. `journalctl -f -o json`) that continuously streams lines to the standard output.

I would like to retrieve this output **line by line** and process it further.

The documentation of `os/exec` addresses how to read the output of a command, and `io` deals with stream buffering.

Everywhere I looked, the handling goes through a fixed buffer that is read into, handled, and written further. My problem is that the size of this buffer is fixed and independent of the content.

**Is there a way to read an incoming stream (in my case - the output of a shell command) line by line? Possibly with a library more high-level than `io` readers?**

Comment: Sounds like `bufio.Scanner` is a good fit. Can you give an example?

Comment: @icza: thank you, I found a way with `bufio.Scanner`. Could you please just bootstrap an answer so that I can add the actual code (I want credit/rep to go where it is due :))

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48353768/capture-stdout-from-command-exec-in-real-time/48381051#48381051, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35221537/goland-reading-liner-per-line-output-of-a-command, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62586549/how-to-call-an-external-program-and-process-its-output/62588308#62588308, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38866952/streaming-commands-output-progress-from-goroutine/38870609#38870609, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46722896/trying-to-return-live-realtime-output-from-shell-command-as-string-data-from-fun, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Cmd.StdoutPipe()`](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#Cmd.StdoutPipe) to obtain the (piped) output of the process before you start it with [`Cmd.Start()`](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#Cmd.Start) (`Start()` starts the command but does not wait for it to complete).

And use a [`bufio.Scanner`](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#Scanner) to read an input (`io.Reader`) line-by-line.

For example I'm gonna use this bash script that prints the current time 3 times, sleeping 1 second between them:

```
for i in {1..3}; do date; sleep 1; done
```

Example executing this and reading its output line-by-line:

```
cmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", "for i in {1..3}; do date; sleep 1; done")
out, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer out.Close()

err = cmd.Start()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

scanner := bufio.NewScanner(out)
for scanner.Scan() {
    line := scanner.Text()
    fmt.Println("Output:", line)
}
```

Example output:

```
2022/11/29 14:38:48 Output: Tue Nov 29 02:38:48 PM CET 2022
2022/11/29 14:38:49 Output: Tue Nov 29 02:38:49 PM CET 2022
2022/11/29 14:38:50 Output: Tue Nov 29 02:38:50 PM CET 2022
```

(The first date-time at the beginning of each line is from the `log` package, to verify each line is printed after a second delay, the other timestamp is the output of the `date` command.)